# Hierarchy button in html and Jquery Function

Tags: jquery, html

one button is in heart of other button , if set a function to parent of button child button instead of do itself action do parent ,

```
--------------------------------------------
|   ----------                             |
|   | Child  |  Parent (class="btn")       |
|   ----------                             |
--------------------------------------------
```

if  `$(".btn").click(function () { return false; });` child return false too ! not navigate to it's own Link !

**Added :**
it happen within any Clickable element like button in div , div in div , any Hierarchy structure, not just button in button , it`s just sample

Comment: Can you post the markup of your nested buttons?

Comment: its happen when parent is `div` element too

Comment: why do you have a button within a button?

Comment: just sample to demonstrate clickable attribute of parent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called Event propagation. Read more at http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation.

Comment: `$("#parant").click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); return false; });` parent is div and child is `a` elemnet with `href` value , but button has no action on click

Comment: Set e.stopPropagation() on A element. Then when you click on A, event will not be propagated to DIV.